# AWS S3 Lambda thumbnail generation node error in cloud watch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

My lambda function is not generating thumbnail as expected. Here's is my **node** code. I uploaded a .zip file with node modules.

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 250;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 250;

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
    var dstKey    = "thumb-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1].toLowerCase();
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback(`Unsupported image type: ${imageType}`);
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                console.log('Width logggg' + size.width);
                console.log('height logggg' + size.height)
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(

                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

I've just pasted the code from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

I implemented everything correct in Lambda, S3 trigger, and bucket names. But in Cloudwatch metrics, I'm getting this error.
[image]

Please tell me about my mistake.

How to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that the error is happening in the file `/var/task/index.js` on line 57, column 38 so that's the best place to start.

If I had to guess though, if we're assuming the `transform` function is what is in `index.js`, it might be that `size` does not have a `width` property. Might be worth logging there to see what's going on.

```
function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width, // <-- here
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
```

Idk what `gm(response.Body).size()` expects for its callback but it would be good to log the params that get passed here.

Comment: Not able to log the params bro. Tried now. Not showing in Cloudwatch metrics